# Sequential Impulses in 3D with friction

Tags: 3d, collision-resolution

I'm currently writing a physics simulation in 3D, that uses sequential impulses. I've managed to implement normal impulses, but I can't get friction impulses to work. As I understand I first get two tangent vectors, that are perpendicular to each other and the normal. Then I calculate the friction impulse and clamp it by total friction accumulator in the range of -FrictionCoefficient * NormalImpulse to FrictionCoefficient * NormalImpulse. I tried applying friction at the center of manifold, it seemed to work, but even with high friction coefficient values it slides a lot, so I don't consider it a solution.

Here's my code for tangents calculation:

```
glm::vec3 first_tangent{data.contactVelocity - collision_data.normal * glm::dot(data.contactVelocity, collision_data.normal)};
float lat_rel_vel{ glm::length2(first_tangent) };
glm::vec3 second_tangent{};
if(lat_rel_vel > 0.0f) {
    first_tangent *= 1.0f / glm::sqrt(lat_rel_vel);
    second_tangent = glm::cross(first_tangent, collision_data.normal);
    second_tangent = glm::normalize(second_tangent);
}
else {
    GetTwoTangential(collision_data.normal, first_tangent, second_tangent);
}
```

(GetTwoTangential function is the exact copy of btPlaneSpace1)

And here's my impulse calculation:

```
float frictional_mass1{ totalInverseMass +
        glm::dot(first_tangent, glm::cross(first->GetInverseWorldTensor() * glm::cross(data.relativeFirst, first_tangent), data.relativeFirst) +
                          glm::cross(second->GetInverseWorldTensor() * glm::cross(data.relativeSecond, first_tangent), data.relativeSecond)) };
float j1{ -glm::dot(data.contactVelocity, first_tangent) };
j1 /= frictional_mass1;

const float tempFriction1{ accumulatedFrictions[currentManifold].first_tangent };
accumulatedFrictions[currentManifold].first_tangent = glm::clamp(accumulatedFrictions[currentManifold].first_tangent + j1,
    -0.8f * accumulatedImpulses[currentManifold],
    0.8f * accumulatedImpulses[currentManifold]);
const float deltaFriction1{ accumulatedFrictions[currentManifold].first_tangent - tempFriction1 };
glm::vec3 fullFriction_1{deltaFriction1 * first_tangent};

first->AppyLinearImpulse(-fullFriction_1);
second->AppyLinearImpulse(fullFriction_1);

first->AppyAngularImpulse(glm::cross(data.relativeFirst, -fullFriction_1));
second->AppyAngularImpulse(glm::cross(data.relativeSecond, fullFriction_1));

float frictional_mass2{ totalInverseMass +
    glm::dot(second_tangent, glm::cross(first->GetInverseWorldTensor() * glm::cross(data.relativeFirst, second_tangent), data.relativeFirst) +
                      glm::cross(second->GetInverseWorldTensor() * glm::cross(data.relativeSecond, second_tangent), data.relativeSecond)) };
float j2{ -glm::dot(data.contactVelocity, second_tangent) };
j2 /= frictional_mass1;

const float tempFriction2{ accumulatedFrictions[currentManifold].second_tangent };
accumulatedFrictions[currentManifold].second_tangent = glm::clamp(accumulatedFrictions[currentManifold].second_tangent + j2,
    -0.8f * accumulatedImpulses[currentManifold],
    0.8f * accumulatedImpulses[currentManifold]);
const float deltaFriction2{ accumulatedFrictions[currentManifold].second_tangent - tempFriction2 };
glm::vec3 fullFriction_2{deltaFriction2 * second_tangent};

first->AppyLinearImpulse(-fullFriction_2);
second->AppyLinearImpulse(fullFriction_2);

first->AppyAngularImpulse(glm::cross(data.relativeFirst, -fullFriction_2));
second->AppyAngularImpulse(glm::cross(data.relativeSecond, fullFriction_2));
```

(0.8f is my friction coefficient, I use it as a placeholder for now)

So here's how my collision response works:

1. Get true normal impulse( using sequential impulse solver to get normal impulses at each contact point)
2. Get friction impulse( also using sequential impulses at each contact point)
   (Normal and friction impulses are calculated separately, first normal then friction)
3. Integrate velocities